# Display first Image of the Album in the aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

There are two tables

1) Gallery and

2) Gallery Stack

The albumsnames are stored in Gallery table and related to it  photos are stored in the Gallery stack. What I want is, When displaying Gallery in the listview. I want to show First image of the album in the Listview

Also I am displaying the data from the Gallery table. Please see the listview code for your reference:-

```
<ul class="galleryul">
                       <asp:ListView ID="lstgallery" runat="server">
                           <LayoutTemplate>
                               <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                           </LayoutTemplate>
                           <ItemTemplate>
                               <li>
                                   <a href="Gallery-DetailView.aspx">
                                       <img src='<%# Eval("Id") %>' alt="No Text" /></a>
                               </li>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:ListView>
                       </ul>
```

Please help how to achieve that

Comment: Are you using any client site scripting language?

Comment: @शेखर: I guess, still no. I am not using it

Comment: You will require jquery plugin or you will have to write a plugin. You can also use Update Panel if you don't want to use any client side script. There are many jquery plugins available you can use one of them.

Comment: @शेखर: Can you please help me related to this plugins and all. As I dont have much idea about Jquery plugins

Comment: Here is a [link](http://www.vandelaydesign.com/jquery-image-galleries/)

Comment: @शेखर: i guess it is not related to what I want